# Review "Ghost" Questions With Answers

Tags: discussion, review, unanswered-questions, accepted-answer

Would it be good to have a review queue, that reviews answers given, for questions that are inactive for lets say 6 months or longer? Activity would be referenced to the "last seen" date and answers should be equally old.

As our site is considered a "hit and run" site, we have many questions with good answers, but without a "mark as best" mark.

The goal would be, for the community, to choose the best answer in the review queue and mark it accordingly (possible without gaining rep.). This will give visitors of Web Applications, and possible throughout SE, a clear indication what the best community answer is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea to have something like that in place, here on Web Applications, for the following reasons:

1. extra community involvement, through:
   a. evaluating answers
   b. voting
2. presenting marked answers for future visitors
3. stimulate (expert) answers on *hit 'n run* questions

I know it would be difficult to implement, but still good to have.

In the meantime, or as a replacement, we could post meta questions, containing those ghost questions and review them over here?

Comment: IMO the best is not accept own answers to [meta-tag:discussion] when the post is making a proposal (commenting this because post like this might evolve into [meta-tag:feature-request] but having an accepted answer might make things confussing)

Answer (score 4):

The "allow community and/or moderators" to "accept" answers when the OP has disappeared has been suggested and declined many times. ([Here's one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8692). [Here's another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature).) The SE team isn't going to implement that.

The best thing we can do is to upvote those really good answers.

As for a review queue, that may have some merit. However, I'd think we could accomplish much the same thing by sorting questions by "active" and jumping to pages near the end of the list.